# d3 squares in a grid

Tags: d3.js, grid, location, cells

I'm trying to understand Mike Bostok's square grid: https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1009139

I want to know how he put the locations of cells and I think the following part illustrates it. But I cannot make sure what it means.

```
.attr("x", function(i) {
        var x0 = Math.floor(i / 100) % 10, x1 = Math.floor(i % 10);
        return groupSpacing * x0 + (cellSpacing + cellSize) * (x1 + x0 * 10);
      })
.attr("y", function(i) {
        var y0 = Math.floor(i / 1000), y1 = Math.floor(i % 100 / 10);
        return groupSpacing * y0 + (cellSpacing + cellSize) * (y1 + y0 * 10);
      })
```

Could you help me to understand this part? Basically, how to set the locations of cells in a grid. In my case, I would like to set the location depending on proportion of a variable in my data. But some general sense will be a great help too.

In addition, what is the most difficult is the usage of %. Could anyone let me know why it is needed?

Thanks a lot,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's break it down for `x`.  First, `i` is the index of the cell.  It'll go from `0 .. N` where N is the number of cells minus 1.

```
var x0 = Math.floor(i / 100) % 10
```

`x0` is the x position of which 10x10 group the cell is in.  Since each group contains 100 cells, it's the floor of index divided by 100.  So, think about cell 201, that'll be 2, which is correct.  You need the modulo operate (which returns the remainder of division), though, to wrap after 10 groups.  Think about cell 2001, floor(2001/100) would put at 20, put the modulo in though and it's correctly 0 for the x position.

```
x1 = Math.floor(i % 10)
```

`x1` is the x position within the 10x10 group.  This is the floor of the remainder of division by 10.  The 10 is because we have 10 columns in each group.  Again if you check our tests of 201 and 2001 they both end up correctly in the second column.

Finally the overall position:

```
groupSpacing * x0 + (cellSpacing + cellSize) * (x1 + x0 * 10);
```

Which reads `(pixel group spacing * x0) + (pixel cell spacing + pixel cell size) * ((x0 * 10) + x1)`

1. pixel spacing for each group
2. cell size and spacing for each cell
3. x group position * 10 (because 10 columns in each group)
4. plus position in each group

Comment: Thank you very much, Mark. Such a huge help! I really appreciate it. Can I just ask how you get all this knowledge and skills in d3? The question seems a bit too general but I'd really love to improve my skills in it. I have a background in data analysis using R and have read books in basic d3 but still have a difficulty to understand advanced d3 codes. Any advice will be a lot of help. Thank you very much,

Comment: @Soo, that is a general question.  Essentially, though, I taught myself `d3` by answering questions here.  I already had a solid knowledge of JavaScript and Mathematics.  Couple that with a love data visualization and `d3` is very interesting study.

Comment: thank you for your answer even though my question was too general. It seems learning JavaScript may help to understand a way of thinking in d3. Would you recommend some concepts in JavaScript that are helpful to understand logic in d3?